# unreported exception NegativeNumber; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, class, exception

I have two files:

**NewtonRaphson**

```
public class NewtonRaphson {
    public double squareRoot  ( double input ) throws   NegativeNumber{
        if (input < 0.0 ) { throw new   NegativeNumber("not allowed to input a negative number");}
        else if (input == 0.0) { return 0.0; }
        else{
            double current = 10.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                current = current - (current*current - input)/(2*current);
            }
            return current;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        NewtonRaphson nr = new NewtonRaphson();
        System.out.println(nr.squareRoot(2.0));

    }
}
```

and **NegativeNumber**

```
public class NegativeNumber extends Exception {
    public NegativeNumber(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

When I compile the first one I get:

```
NewtonRaphson.java:17: unreported exception NegativeNumber; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    System.out.println(nr.squareRoot(2.0));
                                    ^
```

1 error

Could someone help me why?

Comment: I would change it to a RuntimeException then it doesn't have to be caught.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're throwing `NegativeNumber`, but never catching it. What kind of baseball is this?

Add a try-catch to your `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    NewtonRaphson nr = new NewtonRaphson();

    try {
       System.out.println(nr.squareRoot(2.0));
    } catch (NegativeNumber e) {
       System.out.println("Be more positive!");
    }
}
```

Or if you never want to catch it (this is not advised):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NegativeNumber {
    NewtonRaphson nr = new NewtonRaphson();
    System.out.println(nr.squareRoot(2.0));
}
```

Comment: ok but you are using the built in NegativeNumberException now. But what if I want to use my own declared exception, if the input happens to be negative?

Comment: @user2761810: then you just change the name. Your naming scheme is confusing, exceptions should logically end with 'Exception'. Just like any other exception. Why would you recreate an exception that does the same as the existing one?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    try{
        NewtonRaphson nr = new NewtonRaphson();
        System.out.println(nr.squareRoot(2.0));
    }
    catch(NegativeNumber e)  
    {
     System.out.println("Exception happend!");

    }
 }
```